# gfortran-9 installed, but getting "no Fortran compiler found" error (Ubuntu Server 18.04)

Tags: python, ubuntu, gfortran

I've just installed gfortran-9 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gfortran-9
```

I've been able to confirm that gfortran-9 is working correctly by compiling and running a simple 'Hello World' program.

I'm now trying to install PyPROSAIL as follows:

```
sudo -H pip3 install pyprosail
```

... but I'm receiving the following error:

```
error: extension 'PyPROSAIL._prosail_model' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

`gfortran-9 --version` shows me the following:

```
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1) 9.2.1 20191102
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`whereis gfortran-9` shows me the following:

```
gfortran-9: /usr/bin/gfortran-9 /usr/share/man/man1/gfortran-9.1.gz
```

Why is gfortran-9 apparently not being found? Do I need to manually set a path to gfortran-9 somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else is having the same issue, I was able to solve this by installing a different Fortran compiler - `gfortran`:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

Comment: How is that a different compiler?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution if you want a different version of gfortran. If you specify the version of gfortran to install (e.g. gfortran-11) then you'll need to create a symlink to it (e.g. ln -s /usr/bin/gfortran-11 /usr/bin/gfortran).

That symlink is created by default if you install "gfortran" but not if you specify the version. That is the crux of the issue.

Comment: It rather seems that Garreth needs to make a symlink for `gfortran` pointing to his specific version `gfortran-9`.